# How get number of incoming call and show dialog like TrueCaller in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on an Application for doctor where I want to show a dialog on every incoming like truecaller.

Is there any way to get number of incoming call and check it in sqflite and show dialog in flutter Application .

Comment: of course it is possible. You need either find a plugin to integrate with the platform channel or write one your self for android and iOS.

Comment: @Darish is there any plugin available?

Answer (score 1):

**0-its work me**

You would have to implement it through platform channel(native) :

**1-add to File `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<receiver android:name=".ServiceReceiver" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
</intent-filter>
```

this action `<action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />` for access to income call

**2-create File `android/app/src/main/java/{your_package_name}/ServiceReceiver.java`**

```
public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            System.out.println("incomingNumberPhone : "+incomingNumber);
        }
    },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

**3- you have to implement typesafe platform channels via Pigeon:**

```
import 'generated_pigeon.dart'

void onClick() async {
  SearchRequest request = SearchRequest()..query = 'test';
  Api api = Api();
  SearchReply reply = await api.search(request);
  print('reply: ${reply.result}');
}
```

`reply.result` its your income call , you can use in your params in your request to your sqllite

**have good time:)**